# Can I prevent the off button from locking the device?

Tags: lock-screens, touchscreen

I've noticed that tapping the off button locks the device under ICS.  Are there any tricks for making it only shut down the touchscreen and wait for the timeout to actually lock the device?

You must tap the off button to disable the screen when inserting the phone into your pocket because otherwise the phone gets spurious input, but frequently you'll want to pull the phone right back out again.

Comment: There's an option for this in CyanogenMod 9, but I'm not sure if it's there in vanilla ICS (I get the feeling it probably isn't, but could be wrong). You can check `Settings->Security->Lock Screen` to see if you have a "Lock Delay" section in your settings.

Comment: There is a lock delay option which works if the screen saver engages, but it's ignored when not when you tap the off button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an option in Security settings: power button instantly locks screen.

[image: strong text]

Comment: Interesting, my Galaxy Note running Android v4.0.3 doesn't offer that option.  It appears Samsung phones running v4.0.4 offer the feature though so probably it'll turn up eventually : http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-nexus/485361-lock-screen-locks-immediately.html

Comment: image link is dead. Better to upload to stackexchange's image server.